# Error "Not a legal OleAut date" while trying to import from excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm trying to import data from excel 2007 file in a c# app and this is the code:

```
try
        {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=old.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();

            string qry = "select * from [margin$]";
            OleDbCommand excommand = new OleDbCommand(qry, con);

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(excommand);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            da.Fill(ds, "dsmargin");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "dsmargin";


            ds.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
            excommand.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

The sheet I am trying to import doesn't has any dates at all. BUT other sheets will and I will need to import the dates as values not as text.

The only solution I have is when I changed the "HDR=YES;" to "HDR=NO;"
But what if I need the "HDR" to be a "YES"?

Sample of header and first raw:
[image]

Comment: can you edit your code and wrap your code after assigning the con variable around a try{}catch{} and report back on the actual exception. also your datasource should be pointing to a table for example `ds.Tables[0].DefaultView` for example

Comment: I made all your suggestions and the error is "Not a legal OleAut date".

Comment: ok `connectionString` have you navigated to the location of where the filename is in the connection string, open up the excel spread sheet and verify that there are no date fields in the spread sheet.. can you paste a screen shot of the column header along with the data of the first row..?

Comment: the file exists, please see the screen shot in the question